# Replicate a data frame by group

Tags: r, dplyr, replication

I have the following data frame:

```
df = structure(list(Group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
3), index = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3)), row.names = c(NA, 
-13L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to replicate the column index according to the Group column, one time with each number appearing `n` consecutive times, and a second time all the numbers appear as a group `n` times, where `n` is the size of the group (similarly to `rep` versus `rep` with `each`).

So the output would look like this (lets look only at Group 1 because it is too long):

First option:

```
df = structure(list(Group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1), index = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
4, 4, 4)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Second option:

```
df = structure(list(Group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1), index = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 
2, 3, 4)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

How do I do this with `group_by`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `rep` and `slice` like this

```
library(dplyr)
```

Option 1:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  slice(rep(seq_len(n()), each = n()))
```

Option 2 :

```
df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  slice(rep(seq_len(n()), n()))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `uncount`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  uncount(n())
# A tibble: 61 x 2
# Groups:   Group [3]
#   Group index
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1
# 2     1     1
# 3     1     1
# 4     1     1
# 5     1     2
# 6     1     2
# 7     1     2
# 8     1     2
# 9     1     3
#10     1     3
# … with 51 more rows
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[rep(seq_len(.N), .N)], Group]
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$Group), 
       function(x) x[rep(seq_len(nrow(x)), nrow(x)),]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `do` and `lapply` to replicate the whole group

```
df %>% group_by(Group) %>% 
  do(lapply(.,rep,times=nrow(.)) %>% as.data.frame())
df %>% group_by(Group) %>% 
  do(lapply(.,rep,each=nrow(.)) %>% as.data.frame())
```