# Expand data frame in R by duplicating and substituting variable using piping

Tags: r, pipe, tidyverse

I would like to expand a data frame in the following way using:

`GX` will be substituted by three different variables `Gs = (G4, G5, G6`) what will all keep the attribute values of `GX`. For each new `Gs` the current `GX` rows must be duplicated and the `GX` name substituted by the corresponding `Gs` name.

```
  set.seed(123)
  df = data.frame(
    "id" = c(rep("G1", 3), rep("G2", 3), rep("G3", 3), rep("GX",3)),
    "subgroup" = rep(c(1,2,3), 4),
    "total" = sample.int(n = 12),
    "C1" = sample.int(n=12),
    "C2" = sample.int(n=12),
    "C3" = sample.int(n=12))

   id subgroup total C1 C2 C3
1  G1        1     3 11  9  9
2  G1        2    12  5  3 12
3  G1        3    10  3  4 10
4  G2        1     2  9  1  7
5  G2        2     6  4 11  3
6  G2        3    11  1  7  4
7  G3        1     5  7  5  5
8  G3        2     4 12 10  6
9  G3        3     9 10  8  8
10 GX        1     8  2  2  2
11 GX        2     1  6 12  1
12 GX        3     7  8  6 11
```

I have one solution that includes a `for loop`:

```
  Gs = c("G4", "G5", "G6")
  for (ii in 1:length(Gs)) {
    tmp.df <- df[df$id == "GX",]
    tmp.df$id <- gsub(
      pattern = "GX", 
      replacement = Gs[ii],
      x = tmp.df$id
    )
    df <- rbind(df, tmp.df)
  }
  df = df[df$id != "GX",]
```

Which gives:

```
id subgroup total C1 C2 C3
1   G1        1     3 11  9  9
2   G1        2    12  5  3 12
3   G1        3    10  3  4 10
4   G2        1     2  9  1  7
5   G2        2     6  4 11  3
6   G2        3    11  1  7  4
7   G3        1     5  7  5  5
8   G3        2     4 12 10  6
9   G3        3     9 10  8  8
101 G4        1     8  2  2  2
111 G4        2     1  6 12  1
121 G4        3     7  8  6 11
102 G5        1     8  2  2  2
112 G5        2     1  6 12  1
122 G5        3     7  8  6 11
103 G6        1     8  2  2  2
113 G6        2     1  6 12  1
123 G6        3     7  8  6 11
```

However I would like to include the solution in a pipe and avoid the `for loop` solution. Is there any more R stylish approach using **tidyverse syntax** to be included in a **pipe**?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can select only rows where `id == 'GX'`, create all it's combinations with `Gs` and bind the original dataframe to it removing the `'Gx'` rows.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(id == 'GX') %>%
  tidyr::crossing(Gs) %>%
  select(-id, id = Gs) %>%
  bind_rows(df, .) %>%
  filter(id != 'GX')


#   id subgroup total C1 C2 C3
#1  G1        1     3 11  9  9
#2  G1        2    12  5  3 12
#3  G1        3    10  3  4 10
#4  G2        1     2  9  1  7
#5  G2        2     6  4 11  3
#6  G2        3    11  1  7  4
#7  G3        1     5  7  5  5
#8  G3        2     4 12 10  6
#9  G3        3     9 10  8  8
#10 G4        1     8  2  2  2
#11 G5        1     8  2  2  2
#12 G6        1     8  2  2  2
#13 G4        2     1  6 12  1
#14 G5        2     1  6 12  1
#15 G6        2     1  6 12  1
#16 G4        3     7  8  6 11
#17 G5        3     7  8  6 11
#18 G6        3     7  8  6 11
```

Comment: Thanks. This would match exactly the result after adding a last pipe line with 
 `dplyr::arrange(id, subgroup)`

Answer (score 2):

This question was previously answered by Ronak Shah [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56376835/replicate-a-data-frame-by-group). Copying what he did there:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(123)
df = data.frame(
  "id" = c(rep("G1", 3), rep("G2", 3), rep("G3", 3), rep("GX",3)),
  "subgroup" = rep(c(1,2,3), 4),
  "total" = sample.int(n = 12),
  "C1" = sample.int(n=12),
  "C2" = sample.int(n=12),
  "C3" = sample.int(n=12))


df2 <- df %>%
  filter(id == "GX") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice(rep(seq_len(n()), n()))
```

Gives you:

```
> df2
# A tibble: 9 x 6
# Groups:   id [1]
  id    subgroup total    C1    C2    C3
  <fct>    <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 GX           1     8     2     2     2
2 GX           2     1     6    12     1
3 GX           3     7     8     6    11
4 GX           1     8     2     2     2
5 GX           2     1     6    12     1
6 GX           3     7     8     6    11
7 GX           1     8     2     2     2
8 GX           2     1     6    12     1
9 GX           3     7     8     6    11
```

Which is very close to what you are after.